# How to keep users from viewing images by URL?

Tags: php, image

Imagine I have an image file `secretImage.png` on my Webspace and I want several users to have the right to access this image on `index.php`. This can easily be done:

```
// index.php
if($userIsAllowed) echo '<img src="secretImage.png" />';
```

The problem is, users could theoretically still access the image by browsing directly to `www.myDomain.com/secretImage.png`. Is there any way to prevent them from doing so, so that the image can only be viewed inside `index.php`?

Comment: "Security" by obscurity: make the secret image URL "impossible to guess", prevent listings, and make sure that only some people get the URL. Once the URL is leaked, the cat is out (although it can be a *nonce resource* as well). Authentication: *require* authentication and reject unauthenticated queries. While there is also the [Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) headed this adds *no* extra security and is easily spoofed.

Comment: (A nonce resource / resource identifier is one that only temporarily exists. Once the nonce is used by account of the resource being fetched - in the case of a true nonce - or a timeout has passed it cannot be used again to fetch the resource: in a trivial case a DB would make the nonce resource to a physical resource - and server it up in leu - without ever revealing or allowing direct access to the "real" resource. This has different implications than requiring authentication.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess to route all requests for a specific folder through a .php file.  In the file, you can determine whether user can see the file or not... if so, deliver the correct headers and the image.  If not, show whatever you want (404, placeholder image).

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP call `GET /secretImage.png` should itself require authentication. For example, you could use basic authenication and have the user send a `Authorization: {base64 user:password}` header.

Comment: @user2246674 Oh, right. In a hurry I thought I was looking at javascript, not php.

Answer (score 0):

Serve your images from a php file via [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) where you check that the user is allowed

So for example, you might have a php file, getimage.php, that accepts a querystring like "?image=mysecretimage.png" and if the user is allowed, it passes it through.  If you go this route, be careful to take appropriate precautions that only your image files are passed through.

Comment: Whoops, going too fast, meant "fpassthru", not "passthru".  There is an exampel for exactly what he needs for passing an image thru right on the page.

Answer (score 0):

User-specific URLs can be guarded through HTTP authentication. There are [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) online, and it is entirely possible through some .htaccess fiddling that you tailor this method to all of your existing images.